# How to add Google Drive scope to google apps MarketPlace application Manifest

Tags: google-drive-api, google-apps-marketplace

I am want to Add the google drive api feed access to application manifest , to be able to access drive files to with 2 leg Oauth , Any help on how to add this ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the below scopes

```
https://docs.google.com/feeds/   //for documents,presentations and other file types
https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/   // for spreadsheets
```

Comment: do you have an example of actually using 2 leg oauth with the drive api?  I hv=ave those scopes setup and still get a 401.

Comment: Are you referring to the Google Documents List API v2 or the latest Drive API? I have a sample of the Google Documents List API v2. Let me know

Comment: Thanks, I'm looking for the Drive API.  I've got a Google Apps Marketplace app that only has 2-Legged Credentials, and I want to get rolling on the new API.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the documents feed, it is equivalent :

> https://docs.google.com/feeds